# Resize all the windows of an application

Tags: c#, winforms

I am creating a Windows app that will have multiple forms in it. Initially, I have set **WindowState Maximized** for all.

My problem here is that when I minimise one form, size of the other forms stay same. So, if I minimize the main screen go to the next screen, the size of the next screen remains unchanged. All I need to do is change size of all the windows at once.

I tried this:

```
Mainscreen mainscreen = new Mainscreen();
this.WindowsState = mainscreen.WindowsState;
```

But I am finding a way to do it for all screens.

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand your question, so if you could be a bit more concise about your question. But, you could store the size of one form in an additional [generic] class then change the size of your forms using events.

Comment: @horHAY That is what i want. If first form is in minimized state, i want next form to be same windows size. So to be precise i want all form to have same Window size of one that is active

Comment: Is it MDI? Or many other windows maintain by your mainform? Listen to Forms.OnSizeChanged event can be one of the bet

Comment: There may be better ways, but I would store a collection of your forms in a class somewhere, along with the size you want all your forms to keep too. Then when you resize one form, like @Eric says, you can use the onsizechanged event tied to all your forms to call the class with the collection to resize them all.

Comment: @horHAY Eric I am bit confused. A small code demo would good if you guys could

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very ugly demo for your reference

```
private List<Form> Windows { get; set; }

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.Text = "Main Window";
    this.Windows = new List<Form>();

    var defaultSize = new Size(200, 100);
    for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        var form = new Form() { Size = defaultSize, Text = "Resize Me" };
        var suppressEvent = false;

        form.SizeChanged += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (suppressEvent)
                return;

            suppressEvent = true;

            defaultSize = (sender as Form).Size;
            foreach (var otherForm in this.Windows)
            {
                if (otherForm != sender as Form)
                    otherForm.Size = defaultSize;
            }
            suppressEvent = false;
        };


        this.Windows.Add(form);
        form.Show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the minimization is the concern and all sub forms launch from a previous form the quickest way would be to have the main form be the owner of the sub form.

If you make a simple project with two forms **Form1** and **Form2** and add a button onto Form1 that launches Form2 it would look like the following.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 lForm = new Form2();
        lForm.Show(this);
    }
```

Passing "this" (which is reference to Form1) into the constructor of show will make sure that when it minimizes the subform (Form2) will also minimize. You can also change the setting of Form2 and set

```
lForm.ShowInTaskbar = false;
```

if you wanted to help make it clear that all of the forms are tied together.

If you are instead talking about having all forms maintain the same size regardless of who started the change and what the size ends up being then it gets a bit trickier and the simplest way would be to make a form manager of some sort that listens to the OnSizeChanged event and updates all forms whenever any form updates. Keep in mind with this that you'll also need to have a test in the form to know whether or not it is the one that started the update otherwise you would get in a sort of infinite loop where Form1 updates causing Form2 to update which then sends out another message which tries to make Form1 update etc...